# How to return an union of entity id's

Tags: sparql

Consider having a list of persons(parent) and their posts(children).

Note that I have simplified the example but it could be parent-child-childofChild-etc, so some entities with a tree of children.

I would like to have a query that returns a union of some filtered(on some criteria) persons id's and their post id's like so:

```
person1Id
person2Id
person1Post1Id
person1Post2Id
.......
```

Given a concrete situation with 3 persons(with properties age,name) where Person1 has 2 posts and the other persons have no posts I managed to do this in 2 ways but both have limitations. So inside the where clause we have:

```
 ?entityId ?p ?o.
 {
    #persons/posts graph pattern
 } 
 filter (?entityId =?person || ?entityId=?post) # || otherChildFitler
```

This works but uses filter so I want to avoid by using union:

```
    {
            SELECT (?person as ?s) WHERE{ #criteria}
            order by ...
            limit 1
    }
    UNION
    {
            {
                    SELECT ?person WHERE{ #criteria}
                    order by ...
                    limit 1
            }
            ?s a <http://www.example.org/schema/Post> .
            ?s  <http://www.example.org/schema/postedBy> ?person .
    }
```

This also works but I have to duplicate the person inner query for each child.
So I tried to somehow use bind like so:
(Assume the inner query returns 1 person that has 2 posts.)

```
select ?s ?person ?projectedOutPerson

where
{
#tag 1      
        {
                #returns 1 person with 2 posts
                SELECT ?person WHERE
                { 
                        ?person a <http://www.example.org/schema/Person> .
                        optional{?person <http://www.example.org/schema/age> ?age.}
                }
                order by desc(?age)
                limit 1
        }

#tag 2    
        bind(?person as ?projectedOutPerson)
#tag 3      
        {
                bind(?projectedOutPerson as ?s)
        }
#tag 4
        UNION
        {
                ?s a <http://www.example.org/schema/Post> .
                ?s  <http://www.example.org/schema/postedBy> ?projectedOutPerson.
        }
#tag 5        

}
```

This retuns posts id's but doesn't add personIds and it has some curious behaviour.

I'm testing this on bigdata 1.3 and stardog 2.

- ?projectedOutPerson is bound ok(tag 2-3) if i select a person with no posts no posts are returned.
- In both db the bind between tag3-4 is not done/joined so ?s is not bound to a person(returns an empty result).
- if i remove portion tag 4-5 bigdata displays selected person(so now bind in tag 3-4 works) but stardog returns ( empty result, person1, person1) so in stardog chaining the binding doesn't work

  ```
  bind(?person as ?p1) #only this is bound
  bind(?p2 as ?p3)
  bind(?p3 as ?s)
  ```

In sparql1.1 docs "The variable introduced by the BIND clause must not have been used in the group graph pattern up to the point of use in BIND. " but each time a new variable is introduced, so I think it should work.

So how can I solve this without duplicating the subquery or use filter.

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you're trying to do, largely because I haven't seen the data that you're working with.  Are you just trying to have as the result of a single variable both people and posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier to answer this kind of question if you provide some data.  If I understand your question correctly, you have some data like the following.  I'm providing it in Turtle because it's fairly human readable.

```
@prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/21115947/1281433/> .

# person1 has two posts, person2 has one post, and 
# person3 has no posts at all.

:person1 a :Person ;
         :hasPost :person1post1 , :person1post2 .

:person2 a :Person ;
         :hasPost :person2post1 .

:person3 a :Person .
```

Now, if you want to select each person, as well as all their posts, you can do it with a query like this:

```
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/21115947/1281433/>

select ?id where {
  ?person a :Person ;    
          :hasPost? ?id .
}
```

```
-----------------
| id            |
=================
| :person3      |
| :person2      |
| :person2post1 |
| :person1      |
| :person1post2 |
| :person1post1 |
-----------------
```

The trick here is that in the query pattern

```
  ?person a :Person ;    
          :hasPost? ?id .
```

the `?person a :Person` ensures that `?person` is a Person.  Then, the pattern `?person :hasPost? ?id` finds `?id`s such that there's a path from `?person` to `?id` of length zero or one.  The length zero case means that `?id` can be bound to the same value of `?person`.  The case of length one means that you'll get every `x` such that `?person :hasPost x`.

Now, in the case of persons and posts, it doesn't make a lot of sense (I think) to talk about posts having other posts, but if you're just looking for descendants in a tree structure, you can use `*` instead of `?` in your property path.  For instance, if you had this data:

```
@prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/21115947/1281433/> .

#      1
#     / \
#    /   \
#   2     3
#  / \   / \
# 4   5 6   7
#  \     \   \
#   8     9   10 

:node1 :hasChild :node2 , :node3 .
:node2 :hasChild :node4 , :node5 .
:node3 :hasChild :node6 , :node7 .
:node4 :hasChild :node8 .
:node6 :hasChild :node9 .
:node7 :hasChild :node10 .
```

You could get `:node3` and all its descendants with a query like this:

```
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/21115947/1281433/>

select ?node where {
  :node3 :hasChild* ?node
}
```

```
-----------
| node    |
===========
| :node3  |
| :node7  |
| :node10 |
| :node6  |
| :node9  |
-----------
```